# Cookie from Spring not being saved in browser

Tags: session, cookies, spring-security, postman, axios

I'm developing a Nuxt/Vue app using Axios to communicate with a Spring server API. I have no experience with Java/Spring and the backend developer is new to Spring but not Java. When I login the server returns a cookie that consists of:

```
JSESSIONID  
expires: 2018-07-19T05:51:47.000Z
httpOnly: true
path: /app
value: 8D797996617A3BEA7A9C461E21B18B20
```

This is not being saved to the cookies tab in the devtools of Firefox or Chrome. When I make requests after receiving this cookie, no cookies are sent. When using Postman I get slightly different results in the response:

```
JSESSIONID
httpOnly: true
path: /app
value: 85943D96998D0833E096EC56145E52E6
secure: false
expires: 
domain: xxx.xxx.xxx.x
```

The x's are the IP address of the server we're running on.

Here are what we think is setting the cookie info in 'application.properties' on the server side.

```
server.servlet.context-path=/app
server.session.timeout=5
server.session.persistent=true
server.servlet.session.cookie.http-only=true
server.servlet.session.cookie.max-age=900
```

I noticed that the Postman response does not see an expiration while the browser does. I think the issue is the domain or expires value, as they are inconsistent in between Postman and the browser.

Comment: Check your cookie policy in your browser.

Comment: How do I check that?